# How to use nested selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just testing out some code snippets in jQuery, essentially the bug in my code right now rests with this segment:

HTML

```
<div id="qi_table">
        <tr name="1">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty" class="qty">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="2">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty" class="qty">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="3">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty" class="qty">
            </td>
        </tr>
</div>
```

JS

```
var sysID = 2;

$('#qi_table tr').eq(0).find('input[name=qty]').val( sysID );
```

I'm expecting the result to be 3 text entry fields, with the first one filled in with the number "2".

The result is that I simply get 3 empty text fields. What's going on? Am I using jQuery descendant selectors incorrectly?

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/1nf6n0vf/1/

Framework is set to jQuery 1.10.1

Comment: fiddle syntax is incorrect, be careful with opening and closing quotes within strings

Answer (score 3):

Your jQuery is fine, you need to have the `<tr>` elements inside of `<table>` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/1nf6n0vf/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your HTML so that the table rows and cells are inside a `table` (rather than just a `div`);

```
<table id="qi_table">
        <tr name="1">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty" class="qty">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="2">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty" class="qty">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="3">
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="qty" class="qty">
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Your jQuery should work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query:

```
$("input[name='qty']", "#qi_table").val(sysID);
```

Then you search for all inputs in the qi_table.

Comment: to many, including myself, using the context argument isn't simplifying it ... makes it harder to read than left to right selectors

Comment: Just because you aren't used to to it or maybe don't understand it doesn't mean it's not simplifying it. Either way it's not simplifying I mean really you're using jQuery -_- So really "simplifying" is most likely not the right word to use. The entire library is junk